# Add three-way merge in documentation rollbacks

Tags: feature-request, documentation, rollbacks

With questions it usually is much less a problem, but in heavily edited topics, it happens sometimes that a topic has been edited 4 times somewhere else before I look at it and notice that a bad edit passed. [mostly of category "factually incorrect information" which the reviewer didn't catch, currently]

To solve this problem, I'd propose to repurpose the three-way merge moderators use to remove stuff systematically in edits and make it available for documentation to easily rollback versions without losing anything else.

Another issue this solves, is being able to properly retain the revision history when undeleting an example while any other example of the topic has been modified in the meanwhile.

[image]

Comment: I need to improve my mouse-writing… It's maybe readable, but not too beautiful…

Comment: I assure you, it's well above average.

Comment: @JoshCaswell well, thanks … but that kerning, uneven letters, varying heights, bit wobbly baseline… it's horrible :-D