# How can I appeal against the deletion of an example in Documentation?

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-examples

How can I appeal against the deletion of an example in Documentation? For questions on Stack Exchange, one can vote to reopen. Is there anything similar in Documentation?

Answer (score -5):

For now, the only thing you can do is rejecting a proposed change which deletes an example. You can also comment on that proposed change to explain to other people why you disagree with it.

Also, if the example gets deleted, you can always create it again.

Comment: "if the example gets deleted, you can always create it again" -> then it loses all the authors, votes, comments,…

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Unfortunately yes, but I think that content is what is most important.

Comment: I don't think the license allows it (assuming it's cc by-sa 3.0, which I am not sure), unless I mention the name of all authors in the text :/

Comment: Yeah, Franck is right. This is a serious problem. The CC by-SA license repeatedly comes back to bite Docs in the butt. [It frankly doesn't make much sense, given its purpose and implementation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332733/are-examples-allowed-to-be-too-large#comment385236_332733). And aside from licensing issues, expressing disagreement by re-creating an example that has already been deleted is rather the definition of a broken system. If you were doing that on the main site, we'd say you were engaging in abusive behavior. The audit abilities for Docs are severely lacking.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Uhm, you always can go to the last version prior to deletion and click "create draft rolling back to prior to deletion", preserving the edit history

Comment: @CodyGray It's still beta. So a bit of brokeness is expected. Recreating the example and linking to the last version of the deleted example should be enough to honour the license. However, as Stackoverflow undoubtedly has realized by now, massive collaborative editing needs quite some problems to be solved in order to work well. It's a higher level of complexity compared to Q&A.

Comment: @bwoebi: Unfortunately, if other changes have happened in the mean time, this is does not work.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I know :-/ Thus I asked for http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329310/add-three-way-merge-in-documentation-rollbacks …